# Etsy API file upload function doesn't work

Tags: python, upload, etsy

I am trying to work with Etsy API, to create a listing, upload images and download files (for digital product).

I have a working functions for listing creation and image upload, but I have some problems with file upload. By documentation (https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference/#operation/uploadListingFile) it seems very similar to image upload, however it doesn't work for me.

The function I am using is this:

```py
def upload_file(keystring,token,shop_id,listing_id,file):
  
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "x-api-key": keystring,
        "Authorization" : f"Bearer {token}"
              }
    
    url = f"https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/{shop_id}/listings/{listing_id}/files"
    
    files = {'file': ('10.png', open(file,'rb'))}
    

    response = requests.post(
        url=url,
        headers=headers,
        files=files
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(response.json())
    else:
        print('Upload failed with status code:', response.status_code) 
        print(response.json())
```

And as a response, I get 400:

> 'A valid name must be provided with a new file.'

Maybe someone has any ideas or have a working function for this task.

Comment: I don't see how this code follows the documentation.  The documentation says the submitted data needs input elements `listing_file_id`, `file`, `name`, and `rank`. and you haven't provided any of those.  Also the data needs to be submitted as standard multipart form data, which you haven't done either...

Comment: So - the documentation states - "Uploads a new file for a digital listing, or associates an existing file with a specific listing. You must either provide the listing_file_id of an existing file, or the name and binary file data for a file to upload." Based on that - it is either listing_file_id (if it is already uploaded) or file (binary) + name. Rank is optional, and as I will have only 1 file per listing, doesn't play any role. I have tried to add data parameter to request with name, but that do not solve the issue. And it should be able to pass 'name' along with binary through 'files'.

Comment: I did try to use listing_file_id with an already existing file, sending it in data parameter in request and it did work just fine. So - the problem seems to be in sending file (binary) + name.

Comment: I believe that **all** of the input items I mentioned need to be in the `data=` parameter.  This code is not sending that parameter.

Comment: How can it make sense to use existing upload and upload new one at the same time? For image upload there are almost the same input items as here and it is enough to use only binary file. I am sure this is not the case. I just need help how to send 'name' item properly, so the API accepts it

Answer (score 1):

OK, got everything working.

For others interested, you need to pass data in this format:

```
files = {'file': ('10.png', open(fileto, 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')} 
data = {'name': '10.png'}
```

replacing 10.png to real file name

Comment: Thanks for this - I'd been struggling to get this to work for too long!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this, the culprit for me was having 'multipart/form-data' in the headers. This is my working method now for uploading on V3 of the Etsy API

```
def upload_images(self, keystring, shop_id, listing_id, image_file_path, image_rank):

    # Upload the primary image
    image_endpoint = f'/shops/{shop_id}/listings/{listing_id}/images'
    image_url = self.base_url + image_endpoint

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.token['access_token']}", 
        "x-api-key": keystring
    }

    extras = {
        "client_id": keystring
    }

    etsy_auth = OAuth2Session(
        keystring, 
        token=self.token, 
        auto_refresh_url=self.refresh_url, 
        auto_refresh_kwargs=extras, 
        token_updater=self.token_update
    )

    with open(image_file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        file_data = image_file.read()
        file_name = os.path.basename(image_file_path)
        
        data = {
            "name": file_name,
            "rank": image_rank
        }

        files = {
            "image": file_data,
            "name": file_name
        }
        r = json.loads(etsy_auth.post(image_url, files=files, headers=headers, data=data).text)

    return r
```