# Having issues uploading a file and image using the Etsy V3 API Documentation

Tags: python, post, python-requests, etsy

Here is a link to the Etsy V3 API Endpoint that I want to use:
https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference/#operation/uploadListingFile

I am trying to upload a PDF onto a listing that I have in draft status. I have looked at the etsy documentation and believe this is the correct endpoint to use however can not seem to get it working.
[https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/{shop_id}/listings/{self.listing_id}/files](https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/%7Bshop_id%7D/listings/%7Bself.listing_id%7D/files)

My function is:

```
def addFileToDraftListing(self, shop_id):

    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.data["etsy_token"]["access_token"],
        "x-api-key": self.data["etsy_keystring"]
    }

    refresh_url = "https://api.etsy.com/v3/public/oauth/token"
    etsy_auth = OAuth2Session(self.data["etsy_keystring"], token=self.data["etsy_token"], auto_refresh_url=refresh_url)
    
    file_path = "1.pdf"
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        file_data = f.read()
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

    data = {
        'name':  file_name,
    }

    files={
        'name': file_name, 
        'file': (file_path, file_data)} 

    r = etsy_auth.post(f"https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/{shop_id}/listings/{self.listing_id}/files", headers=headers, files=files, data=data)

    print(r.text)
```

The result I am getting is:
`{"error":"Either a valid listing_file_id or file must be provided."}`

The etsy documentation states that the only path params required is the shop_id and listing_id which I provide. It is asking for a valid listing_file_id however I can not obtain one as no file has already been uploaded. It is then asking for a binary file:

*You must either provide the listing_file_id of an existing file, or the name and binary file data for a file to upload*

I have tried providing that file in the form `open(file_path, 'rb')` and as `file_data` the latter being what you see above. However both thimes it is providing me with the same error.

Can someone help me with this issue I am facing? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Found a solution thanks to this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76365459/etsy-api-file-upload-function-doesnt-work?rq=2